# How can I avoid showing the sidebar on login?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I´m using Xamarin forms and I'm unable to prevent that the sidebar is shown on Login.

I tried this on my `LoginPage.xaml`:

```
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
    Shell.FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"
```

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
            {
                base.OnAppearing();
                Shell.SetTabBarIsVisible(this, false);
                Shell.SetNavBarIsVisible(this, false);
                //AppShell.Current.remo();
            }
       
            protected override void OnDisappearing()
            {
                base.OnDisappearing();
                Shell.SetTabBarIsVisible(this, true);
                Shell.SetNavBarIsVisible(this, true);
            }
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by side bar you mean the `Shell` flyout then add below line in your login page xaml

```
Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
```

[Docs: Shell flyout-behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#flyout-behavior)

Comment: Oh yes that worked, so it's "Disabled" insted of "False", thank you very much! I will Accept the answer when I can.